# Do we have enough tags to "span the space" of astronomical eclipses and transits? Is something missing or needs changing?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-tag, tagging

We have

- [solar-eclipse](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solar-eclipse) **143** questions

> Questions about the complete or partial blocking of the sun by the moon.

and

- [lunar-eclipse](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lunar-eclipse) **60** questions

> Questions regarding an event where the Earth goes between the Sun and the Moon and casts a shadow on the Moon.

and

- [eclipse-non-earth-related](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eclipse-non-earth-related) **21** questions

> The eclipse-non-earth-related tag has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?

and

- [planetary-transits](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planetary-transits) (plural) **67** questions

> For questions about transits of planets in front of the Sun, as seen from another, more distant planet; for example, the transits of Mercury and Venus which are visible from the Earth.

and now there is the question

- [Can you distinguish a transit from an eclipse when observing Galilean moons?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/47996/7982)

I added the [eclipse-non-earth-related](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eclipse-non-earth-related) and since there was no applicable transit tag I've just created

- [transits-other-than-sun](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transits-other-than-sun) (also plural) **1** question

> The transits-other-than-sun tag has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?

Have we now "[spanned the space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span)" of astronomical eclipses and transits? Is this all okay now? Something missing? Changes needed?

Comment: I think more important than making sure we have "all" the tags to cover a certain topic is making sure the tags we do have are well-defined. I think we should focus our energy on making sure these tags all have clear excerpts and that the questions using the tags are using them appropriately. If a need arises for another tag addressing this topic, then we can revisit what name might be best for it.

Comment: @called2voyage When I ask tag related questions I always include the excerpt or lack thereof in order to call attention to that. I think one's attention can be spread out over both issues, it's not either-or. I can try to write something for these but for me and the way my head works I'd rather understand the structure of the tag constellation before refining each tag's scope. It's like writing the outline before writing the chapters. Of course when writing fiction it's probably a lot more fun writing the chapters first; I'm told I'm not much fun. :-)